# How to make this cypher faster?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, sql-execution-plan

This is the cypher:

```
START n=node:ACCOUNTS(ACCOUNT_ID={id}) 
MATCH (n)-[:PROVIDER]->(p)<-[r:ALERT]-() 
RETURN r 
ORDER BY {o} ASC 
SKIP {s} LIMIT {l}
```

Following is the execution plan:

```
ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  UNNAMEDS239765216", "n", "m", "  UNNAMED3", "p", "r"], returnItemNames=["r"], _rows=50, _db_hits=0)
    Slice(skip="{s}", _rows=50, _db_hits=0)
      Top(orderBy=["SortItem(Cached(  UNNAMEDS239765216 of type Any),true)"], limit="Add", _rows=50, _db_hits=0)
        Extract(symKeys=["n", "m", "  UNNAMED3", "p", "r"], exprKeys=["  UNNAMEDS239765216"], _rows=42563, _db_hits=0)
          TraversalMatcher(trail="(n)-[  UNNAMED3:PROVIDER WHERE true AND true]->(p)<-[r:ALERT WHERE true AND true]-(m)", _rows=42563, _db_hits=614381)
            ParameterPipe(_rows=1, _db_hits=0)
```

Accounts have Providers (one-many) and Providers have incoming alert relations. I am only interested in selecting those relations.

First execution takes:

```
2013-07-18 17:40:54,199 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.dao.AlertDAO  - >>>> GET ALERTS FOR ACCOUNT CYPHER TOOK: 4789 m-secs
```

10th execution of the same query takes (engine is cached, query is parametrized):

```
2013-07-18 17:41:15,431 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.dao.AlertDAO  - >>>> GET ALERTS FOR ACCOUNT CYPHER TOOK: 1586 m-secs
```

Removing the ORDER BY results in following execution plan and time:

```
2013-07-20 23:45:09,317 [main] DEBUG net.ahm.graph.dao.AlertDAO  - ColumnFilter(symKeys=["n", "m", "  UNNAMED3", "p", "r"], returnItemNames=["r"], _rows=50, _db_hits=0)
Slice(skip="{s}", limit="{l}", _rows=50, _db_hits=0)
  TraversalMatcher(trail="(n)-[  UNNAMED3:PROVIDER WHERE true AND true]->(p)<-[r:ALERT WHERE true AND true]-(m)", _rows=50, _db_hits=241)
    ParameterPipe(_rows=1, _db_hits=0)
2013-07-20 23:45:09,317 [main] INFO  net.ahm.graph.dao.AlertDAO  - >>>> GET ALERTS FOR ACCOUNT CYPHER TOOK: 9 m-secs
```

Comment: I think your slowness is coming from the check to see if there is an incoming relationship type of `ALERT`. I don't think there is any way to optimize this, but it would be great if Cypher provided a WHERE clause for checking if a node had at least one relationship of a type, without iterating through all of them.

Comment: A comment about my comment, its not that checking is slow, it's that this will iterate through ALL ALERT relationships you have attached to that node, instead of just checking for at least 1 and returning a positive result on that.

Comment: That checking is coming in Neo4j 2.1, it will be good. @matroyd what times are you getting, and how much data do you have?

Comment: this query shouldn't be slow at all. Is this the first execution?

Comment: how long does it take without the order by? because ordering will fetch all even if you are only interested in a subset. `order by {o}` shouldn't work in the first place, what do you pass in for `{o}` ?

Comment: Peter and Michael, I updated the original question with more details. In summary: first execution takes 5 secs, 10th execution takes 1.5 secs. Removing the order by causes the query to execute in 9 milli seconds. order by {o} takes r.<PROPERTY NAME>